# extra_requires with different version than in install_requires

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a setup.py for a package, where I always want to install packageA of some version, but occasionally with a specific version (1.2.3). What I want to do is something like

```
setup(name=...,
      install_requires=[packageA],
      extra_requires={'foo': [packageA==1.2.3]}
)
```

this way packageA always gets installed but i can force it to install with a specific version by doing `pip install mypackage[foo]`. HOWEVER, this doesn't actually work - the extra_requires apparently does not get applied if the package is already in install_requires? Is there a way around this? What I want to do is have a normal `pip install mypackage` install packageA of a generic version, but allow for a way to install with a specific version.

NOTE: I do NOT want to do something like

```
setup(name=...,
      install_requires=[],
      extra_requires={'foo': [packageA==1.2.3], 'bar': [packageA]}
)
```

as then the normal pip install does not install packageA by default

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want a dependency package to be of different version?

Comment: yup!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Install first the package that you want to install, and then install the dependency package with a specific version. That should solve it.

Comment: is there a way to do it with one command?

Comment: Maybe _pip_'s next dependency solver would be able to handle such a case: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --unstable-feature=resolver mypackage[foo]`. -- https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-1b1-beta-release/3960 -- If you manage to test this, whether it works or not, it might be a good idea to report the outcome to the developers of _pip_ to help them improve the resolver.